# value is not correct for dropdown when submitting mvc form in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have this AngularJS code for getting countries

```
function helperController($scope, $http) {
    console.log("entering the controller");

    var baseUrl = "http://localhost:8000/api";

    //schools

    var getSchools = function (result) {
        console.log("getting schools");
        if (result != []) {
            $scope.schools = result;
        } else {
            $scope.schools = null;
        }
    };
    var onError = function (reason) {
        console.log(reason);
        $scope.error = "No schools seeding information";
    };
    console.log($scope.schoolId);

    $http({
        url: baseUrl + "/schools",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
    })
        .success(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            getSchools(result);
        }).error(function (reason) {
            onError(reason);
        });


    //getting states

    //get the country where country name is nigeria
    $http({
        url: baseUrl + "/countries",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        params: { countryId: 160 },
    }).success(function (result) {
        $scope.NigeriaID = result.NigeriaID;
    }).error(function (reason) {
        console.log("cannot get Nigeria ID ");
    });



    var getStates = function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        $scope.states = result;
    };


    var errorGettingStates = function (reason) {
        console.log("cannot get states" + reason);
    };

    $http({
        url: baseUrl + "/states",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        params: { id: $scope.NigeriaID }
    }).success(function (result) {
        console.log("getting countries");
        getStates(result);
    }).error(function (reason) {
        errorGettingStates(reason);
    });

}
```

This code correctly gets the schools and countries from the hosted api.

This my .chtml page

```
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SchoolID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*<select data-ng-model="selectedState" class="form-control">
                <option data-ng-repeat="school in schools" value="{{school.id}}">{{school.name}}</option>
            </select>*@
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SchoolID,new SelectList("select school"),"Select School",
            new
            {
                @class = "form-control",
                @ng_model = "schoolId",
                @ng_options = "s.id as s.name for s in schools",
            })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SchoolID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <label id="lab1">{{SchoolId}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The first value in the form is "Select School" and the other values are populated from the database.
When I select the next value e.g if the dropdown contains such values
as

- Select School
- Grande Primary School
- Biochem Lab School
- Demgob Fashion School

If I select "Biochem Lab School" and submit the form, the value of the dropdown is supposed to be 1 but am getting 0.

Please help, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked what is submitted by the form? Is the browser sending 1 and then your code seeing 1? 

It could be not populated and the default of `int` would be 0

Comment: yes i debugged and the value being sent is 0.i also used two-way binding to show the value of what was selected from the dropdown - it was correct. it is submitting that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select data-ng-model="person.MaritalStatus" name="MaritalStatus" >
            <option value="9999">-- Select Marital Status --</option>
            <option ng-repeat="c in MaritalStatu" value="{{c.MaritalStatus}}">{{c.MaritalStatus}}</option>
        </select>
```

Try the above, substituting your own variables